# Joining on a non-PK field, does length of varchar datatype determine query speed? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I was given a ragtag assortment of data to analyze and am running into a predicament.  I've got a ~2 million row table with a non-unique identifier of datatype `varchar(50)`.  This identifier is unique to a `personID`.  Until I figure out exactly how I need to normalize this junk I've got another question that might help me right now: If I change the datatype to a `varchar(25)` for instance, will that help queries run faster when they're joined on a non-PK field?  All of the characters in the string are integers, but trying to convert them to an int would cause overflow.  Or could I possibly somehow index the column for the time being to get some of the queries to run faster?

EDIT: The `personID` will be a foreign key to another table with demographic information about a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the length of a varchar specifies it's maximum length.

The actual length is variable (thus the name) so a lower maximum value won't change the evaluation because it will be made on the actual string.

For more information :

[Check this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)  and this 
[Stack overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686/971693)

Comment: i thought looking through the rest of the unneeded, allocated space could slow the query down.

Comment: sql server does not reserve the space for a varchar(x), that would only be a char(x).

Answer (score 0):

`Varchar(50)` to `varchar(25)` would certainly reduce the size of record in that table, thereby reducing the number of database pages that contain the table, improving the perfomance of queries (may be to a marginal extent), but such an ALTER TABLE statement might take a long time.

Alternatively, if you define index on the join columns, and if your retrieval list is small, you can include those columns also in the index definition ([Covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index)), that too would bring down the query execution times significantly.

Comment: I had never heard of a covering index, I'll have to look into that.