# What is the max character length of a UUID?

Tags: oracle, primary-key, uuid

We are using UUID as primary key for out oracle DB, and trying to determine an appropriate max character length for the VARCHAR. Apparently this is 36 characters but we have noticed UUID'S generated which are longer than this - up to 60 characters in length.
What is a suitable max char length for UUID?

Comment: As a UUID is a 128 bits number I'm really curious to see what coding would convert it into a 60 char string.  Looks like either extremely poor encoding, or some other, unrealted problem to me.

Comment: What's your RDBMS?  MS SQL has a dedicated type for UUIDs, and others can simply store the bytes.  Is there some reason you'd want to store these as `VARCHAR`s?

Comment: @user565869 storing them as bytes are terrible for any kind of manual inspection

Comment: Using them as strings is terrible for any kind of performance

Answer (score 231):

[Section 3 of RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-3) provides the formal definition of UUID string representations.  It's 36 characters (32 hex digits + 4 dashes).

Sounds like you need to figure out where the invalid 60-char IDs are coming from and decide 1) if you want to accept them, and 2) what the max length of those IDs might be based on whatever API is used to generate them.

Answer (score 87):

This is the perfect kind of field to define as CHAR 36, by the way, not VARCHAR 36, since each value will have the exact same length. And you'll use less storage space, since you don't need to store the data length for each value, just the value.

Comment: CHAR may use more space than VARCHAR if your character set on the column is multi-byte (see bottom part on http://stackoverflow.com/a/59686/1691446)

Comment: Pretty sure UUIDv4 is only using the latin-1 charset of UTF-8, in which case this wont be affected. Definitely check if you are using a different charset though.

Comment: UUID in string format can only use this set of characters (regex): `[0-9A-Fa-f-]`, which is 23 distinct octets in ASCII.

Comment: RFC 4122 says UUIDs are 16 octets or 128 bits. If you're using more than that much storage, you're inefficiently encoding them. No need to encode the dashes, for example. They add no information.

Comment: @Trenton there's a trade-off between storage efficiency and user friendliness. One could store UUIDs as BINARY(16) for maximum storage efficiency, but someone looking over the DB would not see the canonical representation, and a programming language may only have a means of creating a UUID object from the canonical/string representation, or not have a UUID object type at all; the UUID might be stored in string form in a file, making comparison with the binary form cumbersome, etc.

Comment: @David can you elaborate? The answer you link seems to say that this issue exists when you use a specific deprecated datatype of MySql, so the general advice of using CHAR 36 over VARCHAR 36 for uuids seems very much valid to me.

Comment: @julaine That _specific_ charset is deprecated (3-byte UTF-8), as generally you should use the 4-byte variants when using UTF-8.

A CHAR column is a fixed size, and will take up the full size that is needed to fit the maximum length of data it can hold. If you are using a multi-byte charset, this means you could be using 2 to 4x the space needed.

Example: using 1 byte charset, 36 characters would max. consume 36 bytes. CHAR(36) is best here. If using a 4 byte charset, the CHAR(36) column would use 36x4 bytes (144 bytes). A VARCHAR(36) would use 38 bytes (in the case of a valid UUID).

Comment: @David That makes sense. So this is a general problem of fixed-size-string-columns not working well with the variable-sized nature of most modern character-encodings like utf-8 and probably exists in all databases.

Answer (score 26):

Most databases have a native UUID type these days to make working with them easier. If yours doesn't, they're just 128-bit numbers, so you can use BINARY(16), and if you need the text format frequently, e.g. for troubleshooting, then add a calculated column to generate it automatically from the binary column. There is no good reason to store the (much larger) text form.

Comment: It's ridiculus that you have the least upvotes. This should be the correct answer to the problem.

Comment: @COMMANDERCAPSLOCK To be fair to other voters, I answered 6 years late.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is many years old but using Oracle now they do have a UUID data type you could use.  From their site:

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128-bit number used to
> identify information in computer systems. You can create a UUID and
> use it to uniquely identify something. In its canonical textual
> representation, the 16 octets of a UUID are represented as 32
> hexadecimal (base-16) digits, displayed in five groups separated by
> hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32
> hexadecimal characters and 4 hyphens). For example,
> a81bc81b-dead-4e5d-abff-90865d1e13b1.

So as mentioned above you can use either the UUID type or use a character string of length 36.

You can see more information about the UUID data type from **Oracle**
here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.1/sqlreferencefornosql/using-uuid-data-type.html#GUID-D2BEE2A1-BF6D-4F4A-8EF4-059A6C8FBAA6

Here's a list of other databases with UUID supported.

**MySQL**
https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-uuids
https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/

**Microsoft SQL**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

**Postgres**
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html

**MongoDB**
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/UUID/

Comment: SQLite has a plug-in for UUIDs https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/uuid.c