# SQL creating a Database throws 'MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

when i try to create a database with the following statement

```
            c.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `verify` (" +
                    "`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE," +
                    "`uuid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
                    "`ts` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
                    "PRIMARY KEY (`id`)" +
                    ");").execute();
```

i get this Error:
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397038/uuid-max-character-length

Answer (score 1):

You want the `uuid` to be `UNIQUE` but for string columns:

> indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column
> values, using col_name(length) syntax to specify an index prefix
> length

and

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage
> engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 767 bytes long
> for InnoDB tables that use the REDUNDANT or COMPACT row format. The
> prefix length limit is 3072 bytes for InnoDB tables that use the
> DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format. For MyISAM tables, the prefix length
> limit is 1000 bytes.

So, you can create your table without this index and then to set the index to get the subset of your column:

```
ALTER TABLE `verify` ADD UNIQUE ( uuid(191) );
```

as `767 / 4 ~= 191`.