# In SQL Server 2012, how large is the penalty to update a dynamic type row versus a static one?

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, sql-update, sqldatatypes

It looks like a good practice to use static data types (such as `CHAR`, `NCHAR`, `BINARY`) where update performance is a major concern.

Though I couldn't find any references about how major this penalty is.

Is anybody aware of how big is the loss in throughput if using dynamic data types instead (`VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `VARBINARY`)?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667/why-would-i-ever-pick-char-over-varchar-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

There is no loss. There is no penalty. Use the type appropriate for the application.