# WYSIWYG HTML editors, characters left and MySQL storage Optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, wysiwyg

I want to use a WYSIWYG editor on my `<textarea>`. In my MySQL I limit the varchar field to 500 characters. I also put a limit of `maxlength` in the textarea tag.

The problem is that the editor generated HTML tags on user input (e.g. `<p>, &nbsp;`) and those take up space as well. I prefer not using a very large comment field (prefer around 1000 chars).

I also show the user the amount of characters left.

The problem is that with the tags the 500 limit take up the space really fast.I prefer not to use like 5000 chars if the user just write a short 10 character comment. Is there a better way to implement this to save up space in the database, report the correct chars left and have a well marked text?

I'm currently using [Trumbowyg editor](http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/). I thought about just ditching the editors and using plain textarea, but do want to be able to allow bold text and maintain line breaks.I am searching for an optimal solution.

My project is built in ASP.NET/C# + jQuery.

Comment: I doubt there's a lot to be gained from storing 500 vs 5000 characters in a MySQL database. 

Just show the amount of characters left, and not worry about some minor added html afterwards.

Comment: @Oli just toe make things clear, you think it's ok to make the column 5000 characters and show the user the character left based on the row text?

Comment: Yes I see no problem, unless you're expecting millions of comments..but even then you should not view the comment length as the bottleneck. What kind of datatype are you using for the comment in MySQL? How are you limiting it to 5000 now?

Comment: @Oli datatype is varchar. I put a limit on the column 500 chars. I used maxlength and server check and trim to make sure the database only accept up to 500 chars.

Comment: If it's varchar it won't use the full amount of space allocated to it..so you can make it 5000 and a 10 character will take up about ~12 chars of space.

Comment: This may be an interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667/why-would-i-ever-pick-char-over-varchar-in-sql

Comment: @Oli you mean that if I use .length() to count the chars and it shows 500, if I insert it into a varchar(500) it would throw an exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96568/discussion-between-oli-and-idan-shechter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about setting a 500 or 5000 VARCHAR, as the space is variable anyhow.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that :)

Do a basic count of the raw text in the textarea, and maybe later see if there are comments that generate unusual amounts of HTML tags.

Comment: Looks like the optimal solution for my needs. I especially taken the "Premature optimization" comment into account, this is probably one of the things that I spend too much time on. Thanks Oli.